# bootstrap-datepicker selected date is returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

In my bootstrap v4.3.1, I have bootstrap-datepicker v1.9.0 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker).

I have the Calendar in the below HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div id="select-date" class="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

And below is how I have constructed the calendar:

```
let calendar = new calendar({
  selector: "#select-date",
  pastDates: false,
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yyyy"
});
```

With the below I am trying to the selected date, however it return null.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#select-date").on("click", function () {
    var selected = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    alert(selected);
  });
});
```

How can I display the selected date in `dd-M-yyyy` format?

Comment: I'm not sure where `new calendar` is coming from because it's not the way this plugin should be initilized - https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/